# Android: Why WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID() return disconnected SSID

Tags: android

I am developing an Android App. The app will keep trying to connect to an dedicated WiFi AP when started. This is working. However when I tested to power off the AP, so the app must have been disconnected from the AP, my app still return the SSID of the AP when I use `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()` to check the SSID, why? And how can I update the current SSID when it is not connected, even it return "unknown ssid"?

Below is the method I check the SSID, the app will invoke this method continuously:

```
WifiManager wifiManager; // <- In MainAativity

// ....
int checkWiFiSSID() {
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "WiFi is disabled, enable it now");
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } else {

        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

        // This line always show the AP SSID even the AP is powered down, why??
        Log.d(TAG, "AP SSID: " + ssid); 
    }
}
```

Thank you.

---

UPDATE:

Having read the document carefully, I found that if the WifiManager is trying to connect to an AP, even it is not connected, the getSSID() will return its SSID. As my app is keep trying to connect to the AP once it is disconnected. I guess this is the reason, but I am not sure.

Comment: what does `wifiManager.getWifiState()` return?

Comment: @donfuxx It returns "WIFI_STATE_ENABLED"